# How can I access ID array of its value

Tags: php

I am analyzing someone's else code where I found during debugging the type and values of a class variable during run time:

```
echo print_r($this->_out);

Array
(
    [id] => -1
    [fieldErrors] => Array
        (
        )

    [error] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [row] => Array
        (
            [DT_RowId] => row_177
            [id] => 177
            [last_name] => sdfdsf
            [first_name] => dsf
            [homeaddr] => sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf
            [email] => s@jj.com
            [officeaddr] => wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
            [mobile] => 11111111
            [age] => 11
            [chargeamt] => 11
            [start_date] => 11/11/2011
        )

)
1{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_177","id":"177","last_name":"sdfdsf","first_name":"dsf","homeaddr":"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf","email":"s@jj.com","officeaddr":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"11\/11\/2011"}}
```

I am a newbie in PHP and would like to know how I can access **[id] => 177** value i.e. value 177.

I tried out many ways

```
$this->_out['row']['id'][0]
```

It gave me below result:

```
1{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_177","id":"177","last_name":"sssss","first_name":"ss","homeaddr":"sssssssssssssssssssss","email":"ss@ww.com","officeaddr":"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"01\/01\/2001"}}
```

while

I tried out many ways

```
$this->_out['row']['id']
```

It gave me below result:

```
177{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_177","id":"177","last_name":"sssss","first_name":"ss","homeaddr":"sssssssssssssssssssss","email":"ss@ww.com","officeaddr":"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssss","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"01\/01\/2001"}}
```

and others but its just not giving me the expected.

How can I access the value as desired?

Comment: `$this->_out['row']['id']` looks like it's outputting the correct value of `177` - are you sure you're not executing some other output directly after using that?

Comment: `$this->_out['row']['id']` gives you back the result of that.

Comment: Sorry its the output at the firebug console. It a web app.

Comment: try to search json_encode in your code which is echo. That is giving you that extra result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right. `$this->_out['row']['id']` will return desired result (check why you get also JSON string that is not part of `print_t($this->_out)`.

This will return result `177`:

```
$this->_out['row']['id'];
```

And since in PHP you can access string characters as array, this will returns first character in string (that is `1`):

```
$this->_out['row']['id'][0];
```

And this will throw error as there is no such index (string length is 3, so last index is 2):

```
$this->_out['row']['id'][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

The print_r result is an array with more arrays on it. So first of all you must find the index of the main array which index represents the sub-array with the value you are looking for. And then you must use this index to access the sub array values.